# android user requesting friends list gets a null

Tags: php, android

Im getting a null point exception when i runs this code.

what i tried to do is... get the useremail from the application to the string uemail and tried to fetch the friends who are friends with uemail.

activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected static final String TAG_Name = null;
    int a;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a = 2;
        Button ref = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                InputStream is = null;
                String result = "";

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                String uemail = String.valueOf(a);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("place_id", uemail));
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://www.hopscriber.com/test.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                }
                // convert response to stringtry
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                try {
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    if (jsonArray != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(TAG_Name, object.getString("place_id"));

                            contactList.add(map);

                        }
                    }
                    TextView z = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                    z.setText(TAG_Name);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

php

```
<?php
include "db_config.php";

$q=mysql_query("SELECT 'name' FROM places WHERE place_id='".$_REQUEST['place_id']."'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

i seems can't find the answer.... please help me out.. it tigers null

Comment: Please put some more code of your java file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed an issue with the `mysql_query` line and where the following `"  WHERE uname='".$_REQUEST['uemail']."'");` not being escaped properly on `WHERE` clause.

The correct PHP is below.

```
 <?php
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT`uname`,`place`,`time` FROM `check_in` 
 WHERE uname='".$_REQUEST['uemail']."'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $output[]=$row;
 print(json_encode($output));
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Your java looks fine as long as you're never invoking `tryme()` (say in a main method without defining `userName` prior).

Comment: hey bro.. i just added the test project i tried to run. i get null always.

Comment: Revert this question, back to when I answered it. Make another question (based on your current edit), and include a `mysql fiddle` of your database, the `NameValuePair` class and `BasicNameValuePair` class and I'll look into what the problem is with your java. Regards

Answer (score 1):

WARNING

```
uname='".$_REQUEST['uemail']."'"
```

is a massive SQL injection attack hole.  Please use the correct escaping of your variables.

Now, where were we?

On the PHP side you have a " after `check_in` that is making a syntax error.  You will not have the JSON array.

Without more code or logs, can't determine where the NULL pointer exception is.

Comment: Just remove the " after the check_in in your SQL.  Also adding a space between SELECT and the first field might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> at hopscriber.com.Menu.tryme(Menu.java:224)

check your method `tryme` in file `Menu.java` line 224. Null Pointer Exception is occurring there

Answer (score 0):

This line has the problem...

```
  private void tryme() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String uemail = String.valueOf(usernameName);  
    // here the uemail is getting null
```

The value of `uemail` is `NUll` and so Null Pointer Exception Occurs.

Comment: i checked it... it gets the email from the application so there is no error in it. can u please tell me is the code is correct with including the php thnx

Comment: Can you please put the whole class...with the class name..and also complete logcat output.

Comment: Have you tried to Toast the value of uemail..I am sure it's getting the NULL value.Please try to Toast the value of uemail by commentting the rest code in your file.
String uemail = String.valueOf(usernameName);